# Voice activated personal audio recorder with live rewind (time shifting) and wall clock stamping

Tags: audio, audio-recording, voice-recording

I'm looking for means of implementing (or finding existing one) "personal audio recorder" like that of video cable companies when you can pause a live stream and play it back with the delay often called as [time shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_shifting). It would be nice if it supports [VOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice-operated_switch) and somehow embeds wall clock stamps, e.g., in between mp3 frames or so, for navigation.

I'm open for any suggestions either as final software or libraries I could use. I'm not even sure if there is any audio format for sparse (wall clock tagged) recording. I know I can put arbitrary stuff between mp3 frames, so hence my thoughts instead of keeping a sidecar file.

The incentive for this is to consider cutting intermediate steps to improve latency by directly recording [HAM radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio) communication via [SDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio) during ultramarathones to enter live feed to [ultralive](http://ultralive.net/) as runners pass through aid stations. This would be an auxiliary operation and I don't want to get in a way between aid station operators and net control, but I'd like to passively record and be able to rewind on the go if I didn't catch something the first time.

Duty cycle is expected to be way below 100% but overall recording time is huge, e.g. ~36 hrs, so VOX and wall clock tags are important.

Platform doesn't really matter, but I'd rather prefer Windows or Linux.